# Folder Permission Issue on Windows Server 2008-R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to share one folder to users with different permissions like some one need to have only read permission as well as some people will have read, write and modify except DELETION.

I created TWO group as well and put users by their grade. Read only permission I could give, but modify permission except deletion not working. If I give modify that people can delete the same file, when I deny delete permission people cannot modify. while saving the file one notification box will come saying "Please contact your administrator".

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Windows treats a file renaming operation as a deletion of the file and creation of a new file with the new name. Therefore, you must have either the Delete permission on the file itself or the Delete Subfolders and Files permission on the folder that contains the file. You must also have Write Data permission on the folder because of the new-file creation.

I know it sounds a bit weird, but there is no way around it.

Comment: Thanks Bart De Vos for reply..  Don't you have any other option to give permission as i mentioned above ?                                                    Can anyone help me...